# Debug Samsung Android 4.4.2 native browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-devtools, samsung-mobile

I am trying to debug the native Samsung android 4.4.2 browser but it does not show in the Chrome inspect. I open chrome browser and shows with no problem. I tested with other devices with 4.4.2 and the native browser shows as a webview but Samsung native browser seems to be different from the standard and it does not show at all. I need to debug JS file. have someone been able to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

The Android stock browser (`com.android.browser`) as of 4.4 uses Chromium WebView, which allows you to debug it. I believe the Samsung version is built on top of this, so it is possible you need to enable a setting. Check out `about:debug` or the Settings menu, and see if there's an option for it. Otherwise, it's possible the older version doesn't expose the debugging features. I know that the Samsung browser on the Android 5 test phone I tried at work allowed me to debug fine.

Comment: Brilliant! I was able to see JS console on both Samsung "native" browser and Meizu. They seem to use same engine - Andorid WebView. I was like a blind man before I enabled debug mode. And frankly, how limited that engine must be not to support nullified function parameters? `function mijn(event = null)`? Crazy. Not to mention no ES5/ES6 support.

Answer (score -1):

To debug this I use weinre and ngrok

Weinre will give you a local debugger on a local port https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

ngrok creates a proxy to a port on you comp (point to weinre) 
https://ngrok.com/

then change the weinre tag to the ngrok generated one and you will get logs and the DOM

Comment: I tried weinre let me see dom, css, But I would like to debug the app, like I do with chrome or webviews and standard android devices, what I have read 4.4.2 samsung native browser is a customized browser by Samsung.